# How to enable ajax access to local files in any Android browser?

Tags: browser, files

On Desktop, some browsers provide an option to enable ajax access to local files. For Chrome, it's the command line option "--allow-file-access-from-files". For Firefox, it's the config variable security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy. By enabling ajax access to local files, we can use javascript to load local files dynamically, which is essential for developing no-backend web apps.

Is there an equivalent way to enable ajax access to local files in any Android browser?

Comment: The browsers are independent softwares, it depends on them, what do they allow. I think it is impossible to make it generally. The browser process has access to the files, and it depends on it, what is it doing to `file:///` URLs. They typically forbid it on good reasons (to prevent websites to upload your local files to them behind your back).

Comment: What could maybe work: starting a webserver on a local port, which does a static file service. For example, the app would run in html/js/css on `file:///<path`, and the webserver would share the app working directory on `http://localhost:8080`. Then the app would be able to access the local file on `<script src="http://127.0.0.1/path"></script>"`. You need to tune the webserver to embed the served files into JSON.